# how to refresh a specific div content with fade in & fade out

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

how to refresh a specific div content with fade in & fade out, im create like this. when i click button nothing happening.

javascript

```
$('#btn_click').click(function(){
  $('#postinganrefresh').fadeIn(1000);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#postinganrefresh').fadeOut(1000, function(){
      location.reload(true);
    });
  });
});
```

button click

```
<a style="float: right;" class="btn btn-default" id="btn_click">
  <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Refresh
</a>
```

specific div to refresh

```
<div class="container" id="postinganrefresh">
  mycontent table
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: im not sure..that all i write in my code..
where i have to add jquery?

Comment: im already add jquery in my header.php
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Use `fadeIn(timeout, function()...` rather than `setTimeout`  (like you do with fadeOut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the jQuery API (http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) but you should include jQuery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6nuopwau/

Answer (score 0):

With your `location.reload(true);` you reload the hole page.

You gave your `setTimeout(` not time to set off. Write it so `setTimeout(function(){ ... },2000);`

If you want to reload only the div content, than take a look at the jQuery function `$.ajax`.
Like:

```
$('#postinganrefresh').fadeOut(1000, function(){
 var t=$(this);
 $.ajax({type:"POST",url:window.location.href, data:{'somePostData':'andTheValue','post2':'value2' }}).always(function(e){
  t.html(e);
 });
});
```